# Dominated convergence theorem: a simple application

Tags: integration, functional-analysis

Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Consider the following 
$$
     \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)e^{-i\zeta x}\,\frac{e^{-ihx}-1}{h}dx
$$
How can I justify that I can pass the limit into the integral? I guess I can use the Dominated convergence theorem but
$$
 \vert f(x)e^{-i\zeta x}\,\frac{e^{-ihx}-1}{h} \vert \le \vert\frac{2}{h}f(x)\vert
$$
and now I can not say that this is less than $\vert 2f(x)\vert$ (which is integrable) because $h$ can be less than $1$. Also, the dominated convergence theorem that I saw was only for limits with $h\rightarrow \infty$ and $h$ an integer.

Comment: There is a "continuous" version of the DCT; as for your worry about sending $h \to 0$ instead of $h \to \infty$, just consider the change of variables $h \mapsto 1/h$. As for your estimates, you may wish to use a standard bound from the Taylor expansion of the exponential function.

Comment: Is $f$ real-valued? If not, would you mind making it more readable by absorbing some factors and writing it as $\int f(x)\frac{e^{ihx}-1}hdx$?

Comment: @barto Maybe I should have said that $f$ is a Schwartz function. In particular, it can be complex-valued.
But would that matter? Don't we have $\vert f(x)e^{-i\zeta x} \frac{e^{-ihx}-1}{h}\vert = \vert f(x) \frac{e^{-ihx}-1}{h}\vert$ ?

Comment: The mean value theorem gives you that $\frac{e^{-ihx}-e^{-i0x}}{h-0}=x e^{-ih'x}$ for some $h'$. If $f(x)\cdot x$ is also $L^1$ then you get the bound that you want, if it isn't $L^1$ then pulling the limit into the integral will result in you trying to integrate a function that isn't $L^1$.

Answer (score 2):

> I can not say that this is less than $|2f(x)|$ (which is integrable) because $h$ can be less than $1$.

Indeed. $\frac1h$ is not bounded as $h\to0$, but $\frac{e^{-ihx}-1}{h}$ is! (for fixed $x$)

More specifically, $|e^{z}-1|\leq (e-1)|z|$ for $|z|\leq 1$:
$$\left|\frac{e^z-1}z\right|=\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^{n-1}}{n!}\right|\leq e-1$$

So $\left|\frac{e^{-ihx}-1}{h}\right|\ll|x|$. Assuming $\int|f(x)x|dx<\infty$ (e.g. if $f$ is a Schwarz function) the Dominated Convergence Theorem applies.

> Also, the dominated convergence theorem that I saw was only for limits with $h\to\infty$ and $h$ an integer.

Recall that if $g$ is a function defined in a neighborhood of $0$, then $\lim_{h\to 0}g(h)=L$ iff $\lim_{h_n\to 0}g(h_n)=L$ for all sequences $h_n \to0$ (with $h_n\neq0$). Now let
$$g(h)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(x)e^{-i\zeta x}\,\frac{e^{-ihx}-1}{h}dx$$
This idea allows to reduce the limit-integral exchanging issue to the case of sequences (here: $h_n$).

Comment: I do not see how I can use the mean value theorem to prove that, though

Comment: @Soap note that
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{-ihx} - 1}{h} = \left.\frac d{dt}e^{-iht} \right|_{t = 0}
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, but I do not want to take the limit yet. I want an inequality for all $h$ (and all $x$)

Comment: @Soap the point is that $\frac{e^{-ihx} - 1}{h}$ is an "average rate of change", hence the mean value theorem.

Comment: Hmm... It doens't seem so obvious now why we can exchange them. It seems like the integral has to be treated more carefully because of factors $x$ that appear. (By the way, note that the MVT for complex functions does not take the same form as for real functions.)

Comment: @barto then perhaps it is best to observe that $x \mapsto \frac{e^x - 1}{x}$ is analytic.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left|
\frac{e^{ihx} - 1}{h} 
\right|
=
\left|
\frac{\left[1 + hx \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(h x)^k}{(k+1)!} i^{k+1} \right] - 1}{ h }
\right| 
=
\left|
x \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(hx)^k}{(k+1)!} i^{k+1}
\right| 
\leq |x| \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{|hx|^k}{k!} = |x|e^{|hx|}
$$